# Can I Promote Notes About Uninitialized Variables to Errors

Tags: error-handling, sas, warnings

When SAS encounters an uninitialized variable, it will output a note to the log that looks like this:

```
NOTE: Variable not_in_data is uninitialized.
```

Is it possible to have SAS output that message as a warning or an error instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes (in 9.4 or later):

`option varinitchk = error;`

Default value is `note`, other possible values are `nonote` and `warning`.

There is also undocumented feature that changes certain notes to errors. You can either set the option using `option dsoptions = note2err`; or by adding `/ note2err` to a data statement. I found a list on SAS-L of the notes this option changes to errors:

```
19   Variable %*v is uninitialized.
97   Missing values were generated as a result of
98   Division by zero detected at %2q.
99   Mathematical operations could not be performed
108  Invalid numeric data, '%*s' , at %2q.
109  Invalid character data, %f , at %2q.
110  Invalid %sargument to function %b at %2q.
139  Argument to function %*s is not a known variable name:  %*v.
140  Argument to function %*s is not a valid variable name:  %*s.
205  Invalid argument(s) to the exponential operator "**" at %2q.
208  Invalid numeric data, %*s='%*s' , at %2q.
209  Invalid character data, %*s=%f , at %2q.
223  A number has become too large at %2q. %w%*s
224  A number has become too large during the compilation phase.
225  Division by zero detected during the compilation phase.
242  Invalid argument(s) to the exponential operator "**".
258  Invalid argument to function %*b at %2q.
259  Invalid first argument to function %*b at %2q.
260  Invalid second argument to function %*b at %2q.
261  Invalid third argument to function %*b at %2q.
262  Invalid fourth argument to function %*b at %2q.
267  Argument %d to function %*b at %2q is invalid.
356  The SUBSTR pseudo-variable function does not allow character
424  Character values have been converted to numeric
425  Numeric values have been converted to character
429  A number has become too large during the compilation phase,
430  Division by zero detected during the compilation phase,
484  Format %*b was not found or could not be loaded.
485  Informat %*b was not found or could not be loaded.
```

[Source](https://listserv.uga.edu/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0610A&L=SAS-L&P=R20689)

Comment: This is great... too bad they didn't expand on this to cover other things like automatic type conversions.

Comment: There is actually an undocumented feature that changes certain notes to errors. You can either set the option using `option dsoptions = note2err;` or by adding `/ note2err` to a particular data step. This works for uninitialized variables and implicit type conversions. I do not know what other notes it might convert.

Comment: +1 on dsoptions=note2err.  It makes a LOT of bad notes become errors.  Hope one day they will document it to make it official.

Comment: @Dwal That is fantastic.  I've been looking for something like that for years.  I think you should actually include mention of that in your answer to make it more prominent.  IMO most of those notes are actually errors.  Too many people program by coincidence (https://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/coincidence) and unfortunately SAS seem supportive of it.

Comment: Side note... this is similar to why using OPTION EXPLICIT in VBA to elevate potential problems into errors is good programming practice. See discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2454583/1056935

Comment: oddly enough I have two people on my team running the same code and one person is getting "NOTE: variable is uninitialized" and another person is getting "ERROR: variable is uninitialized". I'd be surprised if one of them had used an undocumented options statement so I'm still trying to figure out why this would happen