# Detect operation on missing values during SAS datastep

Tags: sas

Is there a way to detect that operations were performed on missing values during a SAS datastep? I've looked at all the [automatic macro variables](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003167023.htm) but none seem to do what I need. I don't think I can set the strictness of SAS code checking so that the `NOTE: Missing values were generated...` message becomes an error (which would presumably give `&syscc` some value).

Sample code:

```
data _null_;
foo=1;
bar=2;
baz=foo*bar;
put foo= bar= baz= "syscc=&syscc syserr=&syserr";
foo=.;
bar=2;
baz=foo*bar;  /*<-- at this point the note about missing values is generated */
/* Here I'd like to be able to do something like; */
/* if [SOME CONDITION] then do;
/*   put "operation on missing values occured!" _ALL_;
/*   [DO SOMETHING];
/* end; */
put foo= bar= baz= "syscc=&syscc syserr=&syserr";
foo=2;
bar=3;
baz=foo*bar;
put foo= bar= baz= "syscc=&syscc syserr=&syserr";
run;
```

Log output (without the source):

```
FOO=1 BAR=2 BAZ=2 syscc=0 syserr=0
FOO=. BAR=2 BAZ=. syscc=0 syserr=0
FOO=2 BAR=3 BAZ=6 syscc=0 syserr=0
NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.
      Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column).
      1 at 8:8
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
```

Log output I'd like to see:

```
FOO=1 BAR=2 BAZ=2 syscc=0 syserr=0
operation on missing values occured! FOO=. BAR=2 BAZ=. _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
FOO=. BAR=2 BAZ=. syscc=0 syserr=0
FOO=2 BAR=3 BAZ=6 syscc=0 syserr=0
NOTE: Missing values were generated as a result of performing an operation on missing values.
      Each place is given by: (Number of times) at (Line):(Column).
      1 at 8:8
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
```

The reason I'm looking for this (rather than just checking the values of individual variables) is that I get very few notes about missing values from one datastep that continuously collects data through a socket (maybe one in 10000 lines read from the socket triggers the missing values note) and within the datastep there are a few hundred numerical variables hidden deep within three layers of macro's, and I'm trying to debug this.

[edit]
The `note2err` `dsoption` suggested by Jeff and Joe does something, but it is a bit too harsh. It just stops execution instantly at the point the missing value message is generated without any more helpfull comments in the log. Now the log is:

```
FOO=1 BAR=2 BAZ=2 syscc=0 syserr=0
ERROR: Operation performed on missing value at line 8 column 9.
ERROR: Termination due to Missing Value
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
```

This is not really helpfull (though it greatly increases the need to fix the issue if I leave it enabled). Setting `option noerrorabend` doesn't change this behaviour.

Comment: [This earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328688/can-i-promote-notes-about-uninitialized-variables-to-errors), while not exactly a duplicate of yours, got a a great general answer that might be what you're looking for.

Comment: This isn't an exact answer to your question, but have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328688/can-i-promote-notes-about-uninitialized-variables-to-errors)?  The undocumented NOTE2ERR option might be helpful - at minimum, you'd find out where in the data step it happened exactly (as it would immediately error out there).

Comment: @Jeff Good timing...

Comment: @Jeff, this is exactly what I am looking for! thanks! And this also goes for Joe but I can only @ notify one person in a comment apparently...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you could try this:

```
data _null_;
foo=1;
bar=2;
baz=foo*bar;
put foo= bar= baz= "syscc=&syscc syserr=&syserr";
foo=.;
bar=2;
baz=foo*bar; 
if missing(foo) or missing(bar) then put "operation on missing values occured!" _all_;
else put "operation is Ok!";
put foo= bar= baz= "syscc=&syscc syserr=&syserr";
foo=2;
bar=3;
baz=foo*bar;
put foo= bar= baz= "syscc=&syscc syserr=&syserr";
run;
```

Comment: It seems to me the OP wants a solution to this that isn't dependent on the individual calculation - rather based on the status of the data step notes/warnings entirely.

Comment: Yes, there are hundreds of variables that change value (and are looped over) in several layers of macros. Checking them all each step is a possibility, but not a very easy one.